# python ctypes and C++ pointers

Tags: python, c++, pointers, ctypes

C++ funtion:

```cpp
DLLENTRY int VTS_API
    SetParamValue( const char *paramName, void *paramValue ) //will return zero(0) in the case of an error
  {
    rtwCAPI_ModelMappingInfo* mmi = &(rtmGetDataMapInfo(PSA_StandAlone_M).mmi);
    int idx = getParamIdx( paramName );
    if (idx<0) {
      return 0;                        //Error
    }

    int retval = capi_ModifyModelParameter( mmi, idx, paramValue );
    if (retval == 1 ) {
      ParamUpdateConst();
    }

    return retval;
  }
```

and my Python code:

```py
import os
from ctypes import *

print(os.getcwd())
os.chdir(r"C:\MY_SECRET_DIR")
print(os.getcwd())

PSAdll=cdll.LoadLibrary(os.getcwd()+"\PSA_StandAlone_1.dll")

setParam=PSAdll.SetParamValue
setParam.restype=c_int

setParam.argtypes=[c_char_p, c_void_p]

z=setParam(b"LDOGenSpdSetpoint", int(20) )
```

returns

```
z=setParam(b"LDO_PSA_GenSpdSetpoint01", int(20) )
WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000020
```

Any idea what can help?
I already tried `POINTER` and `byref()`, but I am getting the same output

Comment: What does `capi_ModifyModelParameter` do with the `paramValue` pointer? Though passing a "random" integer like 20 is pretty much never correct

Comment: Just a quick hint: it is generally not recommended to use `ctypes` directly. [cffi](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html) provides a much easier and robust interface.

Answer (score 1):

*SetParamValue* expects a pointer (*void** or *c_void_p*) as the 2<sup>nd</sup> argument, but you're passing an *int*. 
The function will interpret it as a pointer (memory address), and when attempting to dereference it (to get its content), it will *segfault* (*Access Violation*), as the process doesn't have permissions on that address.

To fix the problem, pass the proper arguments to the function:

```py
z = setParam(b"LDOGenSpdSetpoint", pointer(c_int(20)))
```

You can find more details on [[Python 3]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).